# How to set the input tag as enabled?

Tags: javascript, disabled-input, attribution

```js
var startat = 5;
function disableRegBtn(bdisable){
    document.getElementById('regBtn').disabled=bdisable;
}
 
function showTime(){
    if(startat == 0){
        clearInterval(timeId);
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "please register now";
        disableRegBtn("enabled");
        return;
        }
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "please register in  " + startat + "  second(s)";
    startat--;      
}
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById('taid').readOnly=true;
    disableRegBtn(true);
    timeId=setInterval("showTime()",1000);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="taid" cols="30" rows="5">Registration Agreement:
1.xxxxxx
2.xxxxxx
3.xxxxxx
</textarea> <p id="p1"><input id="regBtn" type="button" value="register" /></p>
```

I want to make people read the registration agreement at least 5 seconds before they submit their registration,when 5 second is over,`please register now` can show in webpage,how to make  `<input id="regBtn" type="button" value="register" />` work?

I make some tries for `disableRegBtn()` in `showTime` function.

```
disableRegBtn(false)
disableRegBtn("false")
disableRegBtn("disabled")
disableRegBtn("enabled")
```

None of them can take effect.

Comment: Note your code is currently deleting your button, ie innerHTML of p1 is being overwritten, so there is no way of re-enabling it since you got rid of it all together. The `disableRegBtn(false)` will work as the `disabled` property is a boolean value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to create the button again as it is already in the DOM.

You can use variables to hold the elements so that you can use them when you need them. This will ensure that your code is more clean and robust.

Instead of passing *enabled*, you can pass `flase` when the counter is `0`. I will also suggest you to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` when dealing with text only content as it is more faster an predictable.

```js
var startat = 5;
var buttonEl = document.getElementById('regBtn');
var pEl = document.getElementById("p1");
function disableRegBtn(bdisable){
  buttonEl.disabled = bdisable;
  pEl.textContent = '';
  pEl.prepend(buttonEl);
}
 
function showTime(){
  if(startat == 0){
    clearInterval(timeId);
    pEl.textContent = "please register now";
    disableRegBtn(false);
    return;
  }
  
  pEl.textContent = "please register in  " + startat + "  second(s)";
  startat--;      
}
window.onload=function(){
  document.getElementById('taid').readOnly=true;
  disableRegBtn(true);
  timeId=setInterval("showTime()",1000);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="taid" cols="30" rows="5">Registration Agreement:
1.xxxxxx
2.xxxxxx
3.xxxxxx
</textarea> <p id="p1"><input id="regBtn" type="button" value="register" /></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

your button deleted while doing `document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "please register in...` just add the button again after timeout

```js
var startat = 5;

function disableRegBtn(bdisable) {
  document.getElementById('regBtn').disabled = bdisable;
}

function showTime() {
  if (startat == 0) {
    clearInterval(timeId);
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = '<input id="regBtn" type="button" value="register" />';
    return;
  }
  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "please register in  " + startat + "  second(s)";
  startat--;
}
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('taid').readOnly = true;
  disableRegBtn(true);
  timeId = setInterval("showTime()", 1000);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="taid" cols="30" rows="5">Registration Agreement:
1.xxxxxx
2.xxxxxx
3.xxxxxx
</textarea>
<p id="p1"><input id="regBtn" type="button" value="register" /></p>
```